# How can I get an automatic thumbnail from the first image in a Wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a Wordpress theme and I'd like to grab the first image in a post as a thumbnail to use in the Facebook's OG meta tag.

I tried using the function `get_the_post_thumbnail()` but it generates an html `img` element. Also I'd like to take the first image in the post, without the need of adding a featured image when creating the post.

This should be simple because there are already all thumbnails generated for every post, I'm just not getting it right.

Comment: I don't know what you can extrapolate from this, but maybe you can download it and parse the code.  This plugin grabs the featured image, and if there is none, uses the first image in the post.  So maybe you can download it and check out the code, and get some ideas there.  Actually, it gets such good reviews, I'm going to download it for one of my domains and check the code out myself -- although it hasn't been updated in a year and a half.  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-like-thumbnail/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I made some function for you that you can hook to add/edit attachment event.

```
function set_first_as_featured($attachment_ID){
    $post_ID = get_post($attachment_ID)->post_parent;
    if(!has_post_thumbnail($post_ID)){
        set_post_thumbnail($post_ID, $attachment_ID);
    }
}

add_action('add_attachment', 'set_first_as_featured');
add_action('edit_attachment', 'set_first_as_featured');
```

There is a lot of space for improvement, but this one works like a charm too. On every upload / edit attachment, function checks if the post already has featured image. If it has not, image in question is set as featured. Every next picture will be ignored (since post already has featured image).

Maybe someone finds it helpful (you found solution in the middle of my coding, so... :) )

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution:

```
$size = 'thumbnail'; // whatever size you want
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( $size );
} else {
    $attachments = get_children( array(
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
        'numberposts' => 1)
    );
    foreach ( $attachments as $thumb_id => $attachment ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumb_id, $size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
 wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' )[0];
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your theme's functions.php:

```
// make the first image of WordPress post as featured image
function first_image_as_featured() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img_featured = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img_featured = $matches [1] [0];
if(empty($first_img_featured)){ //Defines a default image
$first_img_featured = "/images/default.jpg";
}
return $first_img_featured;
}
```

Then add the below code inside WordPress loop:

```
 <?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php } 
     else { ?>
     <img src="<?php echo first_image_as_featured(); ?>" />
     <?php
} 
?>
```

If the featured image not set, it will automatically take the first image as featured image.
Source: [**Get The First Image Of WordPress Post As Featured Image**](https://www.codespeedy.com/get-the-first-image-of-wordpress-post-as-featured-image/)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the solutions above withou success. So, I build a new and easy solution:

```
function set_first_as_featured($post_id){
    $medias = get_attached_media( 'image', $post_id );
    if(!has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {
        foreach ($medias as $media) {
            set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $media->ID);
            break;
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'set_first_as_featured');
```

When you save a post, this code will check if it has any thumbnail. If not, so it will set the first image attached to this post as thumbnail.